# Rails Accessing data in XML - Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, magento

I am trying to download products from a Magento store into my Rails database using the "magento-rb" library located here: https://github.com/joelvh/magento-rb

I've tried the following code:

```
xml_api = Magento::XmlApi.new "http://website.com/api/xmlrpc/", "myusername", "mypassword", :debug => true
products = xml_api.call("catalog_product.list")
products.each do |p|
    @exists = Product.where("sku = ?",p["sku"])
    if @exists
        @product = Product.find_by_sku(p["sku"])
    else
        @product = Product.new
    end
    @product.sku = p["sku"]
    @product.name = p["name"]
    @product.mage_product_id = p["product_id"]
    @product.save
end
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ProductsController#test

undefined method `sku=' for nil:NilClass
```

I should note that I have confirmed that "sku" is indeed an attribute to the Product model, and I have also tried resetting the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello from odesk!

You need to add .first call after where and then it will work. After that you can refactor the code appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote the code, `@exists` is always `true` so even when the sku doesn't exist, the where() method will return an empty array which evaluates to `true` in ruby.

The only values that evaluate to false in ruby are `false` and `nil`.

That's why when you use `Product.find_by_sku`, it returns `nil` because the sku doesn't exist and THAT is why you're getting the error `undefined method sku= for nil:NilClass`.

It's like you're writing `nil.sku = p['sku']` which won't work.

To check the existence of a record in the database, it's better to use the 'exists?' method:

```
if Product.exists?(["sku = ?",p["sku"]])
  # product exists
else
  # product doesn't exist
end
```

You can actually skip the extra record checking and only use the find_by_sku method to both check for existence and get the record if it exists at the same time. The following code does the same thing, but it's more "ruby-like":

```
@product = Product.find_by_sku(p['sku'])
@product = Product.new unless @product
@product.sku = p['sku'] # this is unnecessary
@product.name = p['name']
@product.mage_product_id = p['product_id']
@product.save
```